# XPath expression to select the complete document excluding one element

Tags: xpath

I have an XML document

```
<root>
    <a>Foo</a>
    <b>Bar</b>
    <c>Baz</c>
</root>
```

and need an XPath 1.0 query to obtain the *entire* document *excluding* the `<b>` element, as follows:

```
<root>
    <a>Foo</a>
    <c>Baz</c>
</root>
```

I have tried `*[not(self::b)]` but this just gives me the original document, as does `*[not(ancestor-or-self::b)]`.

The queries `/root/*[not(self::b)]` and `/root/*[not(ancestor-or-self::b)]` work as expected to exclude the  element, but omit the parent root element, which we require.

```
<a>Foo</a>
<c>Baz</c>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath can only select nodes that are there in the input, it cannot modify the input tree in any way. Your input does not contain a root element whose only children are `a` and `c`, so you cannot select such an element.

For that you need XSLT or XQuery.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I was trying to reproduce the results of the XML-DSIG transform ``<XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::b)</XPath>`` under the <Reference URI=""> which, if I understand correctly, 
means "all nodes in the entire parse tree starting at the root node except if the node or one of its ancestors has a tag of <b>".
As you point out, it seems you cannot use XPath to do this!

Comment: You can select a set of nodes that does not include the `b` element. But the nodes you select will be unchanged from the nodes in the input. If you select the `root` element, for example, it will have three element children, and if you select the `a` element, then its following sibling will be `b`.

Comment: And note, the XPath expression `not(ancestor-or-self::b)` doesn't do what you say: it returns a boolean which is true if and only if the current node is not a `b` element and has no ancestor named `b`.